# Visual Studio plug in to jump to test class

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd, visual-studio-extensions

I was wondering if there is a plugin that allows me to jump directly to the test for the current class (Or create it if it doesn't exist).

I guess this should be based on the convention that the test project is named like the project being tested + "test" and the test class is named like the class being tester + "test".

A feature like that would really help in projects with many files and foldes, where scrolling the solution explorer to find the associated test project can be quite annoying.

Comment: Did you try using built-in test feature?

Comment: I am using the ReSharper testrunner for too long, but I am sure to remember that in the Visual Studio test window a simple double click into the list of tests should bring you back.

Comment: Although not technically your answer, I make do with Resharper 6. Ctrl+T, TAM for TestAccountManager to jump to the type. Follow that up with Alt+\, to jump to specific test member.

Comment: Let me be a little more specific on what im looking for. I already use Resharper as my testrunner and I'm aware of the features in that product. Currently im working in a solution with 43 projects, including test projects, and a lot of files. The overview is lost, even using the features of the test manager. Im looking for a tool that would allow me to navigate between the current implementation file and the associated test file and vice versa. Also I would like to be able to create a test file in the right location if one doesn't exist....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about [NCrunch](http://ncrunch.net)? This tool will show you, per method, which and how many tests are covering it:

[image: NCrunch shows how many tests are covering]

[image: double-click navigates to test]

Comment: Thanks... Not exactly what I thought I was looking for, but it does the job!

Comment: NCrunch might do the job and the capabilities look awesome from checking out the website, but it requires your project be setup in a specific way, not cool.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to find a few extensions on visualstudiogallery.com, but ended up writing my own plugin for this. Its not perfect, but i does what I needed.

If anyone else would like, its available for free at testlocator.eqa.dk

Comment: Following extra features would be nice for TestLocator: A. Decorate the files that already have a corresponding test (similar to MoreUnit for Eclipse: http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) B. Support several configurations for different file extensions (e.g. .cs **and** .js)  C. Support tests in the same project (e.g. by allowing  a / in the project extension: <ProjectExtension>/MyTestSubFolder</ProjectExtension>?)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can `Shift+F12` on any class or method definition to find all references. Although the resulting list Studio is not very convenient, but a starting point. Using a tool like DevExpress CodeRush or ReSharper lets you sort and filter by namespace, project, file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use ReSharper, it has a [TestLinker](https://github.com/matkoch/resharper-testlinker) plugin.

It does the job pretty well.

Basic shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+F7.

> Goto Related Files is extended with navigation points to production/test classes.

> New shortcuts ReSharper_GotoAllLinkedTypes and ReSharper_GotoLinkedTypesWithDerivedName (assignable via keyboard options) that jumps between linked types. In case of multiple linked types, a dedicated popup menu is shown, which can also be displayed in Find Results window.

[image: Demo]